# Is there a more concise way of checking a property exists and then checking it's value?

Tags: php, null

I have the following code:

```
property_exists($foo,'bar') && 'x' === $foo->bar)
```

I want to stay away from `@$foo->bar` syntax since it's just bad form.

But I don't want to have to have `$foo` and `bar` on the line twice, it seems unnecessary.

Comment: The idea of writing a function for this purpose is good, but is there a way that it can be avoided? It's such a simple thing to want to do that I hoped there was some more concise language-level support for it.

Comment: You could avoid the whole problem by initializing all your properties.

Comment: I can't really do that here, some of them are created dynamically and I don't want them cluttering up my objects if I don't need them. I guess that's the tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to do it:

```
class Foo {
    public $bar;
    function isset_and_equals( $name, $value) {
        return property_exists( $this, $name) && $this->$name === $value;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
var_dump( $foo->isset_and_equals( 'bar', 'x')); // false

$foo->bar = 'x';
var_dump( $foo->isset_and_equals( 'bar', 'x')); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write a function - maybe need one for each property, or possibly have to suppress errors when you pass in the property (because it may not exist) - I would do it this way (untested):

```
function checkBar($object, $xValue){
  if(isset($object->bar) && $object->bar === $xValue) return true;
  return false;
}
```

usage:

```
if(checkBar($foo)) dostuff();
```